# Any way to make notifications dark theme?

Tags: 19.04

Mostly just the title here is an example of a notification now.

[image: Example of notification]

Comment: So you want to Customize these notifications as dark rite.. can you specify what colors are you expecting inplace of white background and black font?

Comment: I dunno... maybe like a dark greyish background with a white font?

Comment: It seems that the notification has dark text and white background whether or not a dark theme, such as Yaru-Dark is selected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is, but not using the default dark theme, Yaru-dark.
The problem is that Yaru does not have a dark theme for the shell ([see this thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yaru-theme/+bug/1788547/comments/2)).

You can do the following:

1. Install the [User Themes](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) extension.
2. Install Tweaks: `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`.
3. Install a theme that has a dark shell theme. One option is Arc, from the repositories: `sudo apt install arc-theme`, though it doesn't quite fit Yaru.
4. Open Tweaks, move to `Extensions` and activate `User Themes`. Then go to `Appearance`, and under `Shell` pick `Arc-Dark`.

Your shell is now themed dark. [I would love better suggestions than Arc-Dark.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149991/dark-shell-theme-that-fits-yaru-dark)

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on Rasmus' great answer, since a bit has changed on Ubuntu 22.04 and 22.10, you now need to:

1. Install the GNOME shell extension manager (`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager`).
2. Open the Extension Manager, then click `Browse`
3. Click the blue `Install` button for the [User Themes](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) extension.
4. If you haven't already, install the GNOME Tweak Tool (`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`).
5. Launch Tweaks, then click then click `Appearance`, and on the `Shell` drop-down, select one of the preinstalled choices.